# Webpack external require module with complex name

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, webpack

I'm working on an Angular application that integrates into a bigger one. We use RequireJs and I'm migrating to Webpack. My code depends on an external requirejs module in the format:

```
var x = require('foo/foo/bar');
```

Edit: the module is actually a script located in serverRoot/foo/foo/bar.js.

In my webpack.config.js I'm telling webpack to not bother with that module, because it's provided externally:

```
externals: {
    'foo/foo/bar': 'foo/foo/bar'
}
```

This generates the following code by webpack:

```
/* 15 */
/***/ function(module, exports) {

    module.exports = foo/foo/bar;

/***/ },
```

Which obviously raises an error.

So... how can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

The external library or target should expose a `var` to the global context, for example, using external jquery library:

```
externals: {
    // require("jquery") is external and available
    // on the global var jQuery
    "jquery": "jQuery"
}
```

so in you case, if `require('foo/foo/bar')` would expose a `globalFoo` variable, you could set the externals:

```
externals: {
    "globalFoo": "foo/foo/bar"
}
```

Comment: I don't have access to the external library to make it expose a variable... It's located in serverRoot/foo/foo/bar.js